# Favorite icon for Franz is missing on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I installed Franz using the `.deb` provided in the [official website](https://meetfranz.com/).

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you click "Activities" and search for "franz", does it show the correct icon?

Comment: Nop, wrong aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the icon-path provided in the `.desktop` file associated to Franz is wrong or not understood by the shell.

To fix this first copy `franz.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Then open the copied file, and provide a full path to a correct icon file (preferably SVG or PNG) to the `Icon=` line, so that it looks like

```
Icon=/path/to/icon-for-franz.png
```

---

**Tip:** Look for a `franz.png` file in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/1024x1024/apps/`. If it exists and is not corrupted, you can set

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/1024x1024/apps/franz.png
```

Comment: What i did was:

copy franz desktop from /usr/share/applications/ to ~/.local/share/applications/

and then edited it and changed icon to Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/1024x1024/apps/franz.png

worked!